Foreign keys in Entity Framework Core in an ASP.NET Core Web API
I have a small question and request regarding the code-first approach with Entity Framework Core.
Let's suppose I have a class A and a class B.
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> B{ get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<A> A{ get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
                .HasMany(i => i.A)
                .WithMany(r => r.B);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

As you can see, there's a many-to-many relationship between my two classes, and when I run my migration, everything goes well. I get my table A, my table B, and my table AB, which contains A_ID and B_ID.
However, my problem is with my A controller. When I generate it, the POST method requires the A entity so all the B properties, while the user only needs to send the B_ID and not the B entity and if I create another input DTO, I would be obliged to query the B model for each id, and I don't find that ideal.
My question is: have I declared my foreign keys correctly? Is there a way for EF Core's save method to not require the entire B model and to accept an object containing the information of class A with just B_ID?

I think you can declare an property for just the foreign key as a primitive. These A's and B's aren't very informative, but if B is really something like a Product entity, then you could declare a ProductId property as well as  Products navigation property.

Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately, your comment doesn't answer my question. You can imagine A and B as anything, for example, A = Product and B = Category.
Let's say that in my Post Product API, I need to retrieve all the categories (20 queries, for example) before saving my model because my ProductDto only takes a list of category IDs.
What bothers me about this is having to call getCategory 20 times (and maybe more!).

I'm not sure what you mean. If product already has categories in the DB you shouldn't have to get them - this means your product already exists in the db. At most you are only doing an update (adding a new categories to the products list of categories). Also, there is no reason to have to do 20 queries - you can do one query to get all the categories associated with a product. I think it might help if you discard the ambiguous A, B and hypothetical Product, Categories and use a meaningful example that shows exactly what you are trying to do.
